# How do I check accuracy of my training model using Tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I'm running a CNN for image classification. Every 100 steps, a file is created in a folder either as: model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt-0.index, model.ckpt-0.meta. There are also these files: graph.pbtxt and checkpoint.

Which of these files would I use to view the accuracy of my training model in Tensorboard?

Answer (score 0):

None of these contain the accuracy values, they are the definition of the model (graph.pbtxt) and the model weights (checkpoint / ckpt files).

By default the `fit` method will output any losses or metrics (e.g. accuracy) you defined when you called `compile` on the model, e.g.

```
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae", "acc"])
```

will compile the model with the `mse` loss and the `mae` and `acc` metrics. The values will be printed at the end of each epoch, or more often if you change the `verbose` argument when calling `fit`

Perhaps the best way to visualise these values is to use [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started). To do this you create a tensorboard callback (a callback is a class with methods that are called at the start / end of training, epoch and batch) which will write the metrics and other info into the training directory.

Then you may run tensorboard from inside the training directory, e.g. `tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/training/dir` to get a nice web-based UI in which to monitor training.